# Form para relacionamento ForeignKey

Tags: django

é o seguinte criei 3 models, um é o Pessoa, outro é agressor e o outro é Vida
. Sendo que Agressor herda de pessoa (já fiz a herança). E a classe Vida pode ter um objeto do tipo Agressor. Como faço para fazer esse relacionamento 
Utilizo o ForeignKey?
E para fazer isso refletir na hora de criar o template, tipo para entrar com os valores(input) do objeto criado?

```
class ForensicPessoa(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nome')
    birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')
    rg = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='RG')


class ForensicAgressor(ForensicPessoa):

    stature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Estatura')
    color_hair = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Cor do cabelo')


class ForensicVida(models.Model):

    agressor = models.ForeignKey(ForensicAgressor)
    belongings_victim_lf = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Pertences')
```

como faço para acessar os atributos do agressor (objeto) no template ?

```
{{ form_vida.agressor.name }}   ->agressor (objeto criado class ForensicVida)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sara,

Para vincular somente um atributo utilizo o ForeignKey.

Objetos desse tipo são gerados pelo django como um combobox (forms.Select).
Se você precisar passar um objeto específico basta informá-lo na sua view. No exemplo abaixo perceba que está sendo setado um usuário para o atributo correspondente na classe.

```
@login_required
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProcessoForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        proc = form.save(commit=False)
        proc.usuarioInclusao = request.user
        proc.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        messages.success(request,"Registro "+str(proc.id)+" inserido com sucesso!")
        return redirect('new-proc')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "O formulário não foi preenchido corretamente.")
        return render(request, 'new.html', {'form': form})
form = ProcessoForm()
return render(request, 'new.html', {'form': form})
```

Para acessar o atributo acredito que esteja correta. Considerando que form_vida seja a variável que você está retornando no seu render.

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form_vida': form})
```

Espero que eu tenha conseguido te ajudar :)